# Remove Header in React navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Remove Header in React navigation 6 with custom style
here is code foe stack navigation

```
 <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName='OtpScreen'
    // screenOptions={{
    //   headerShown: false,
    // }}
    screenOptions={{ headerMode: 'none' }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
      name='Tabs'
      component={MyTabs}
    />

  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

tab navigation

```
   <Tab.Navigator
  useHeaderHeight={false}
  screenOptions={
    ({
      headerShown: false,
    },
    ({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;

        if (route.name === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
        } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list' : 'ios-list';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
      tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }))
  }
>
```

I use every possible solution still not get the answer I want to use it with custom style as I shown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add like this

```
 <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName='OtpScreen'
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
    screenOptions={{ headerMode: 'none' }}
  ></Stack.Navigator>
```

headerShown: false, this will do work

Comment: `screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}` worked for me, but `headerMode` did not

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v6 following worked for me

```
options={{ headerShown: false }}
```

Here is the complete example for **stack level:**

```
 <Stack.Navigator
    name="Auth"
    initialRouteName="SignIn"
    options={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Here is the complete example for **screen level:**

```
    <Stack.Navigator
        name="Auth"
        initialRouteName="SignIn">
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen}   options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to put **HeaderShow** and **HeaderMode** inside at the same screenOptions

```
<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      headerMode: 'none',
    }}
  > </Stack.Navigator>
```